# Stopping Images being swapped on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to code a checkers game in JavaScript and I am having trouble with stopping images after one swap. In the current implementation (below) the images swap on click and then when you click on another part of the board (a table in this case) another 'piece' is placed. But then when you click again another is placed and another etc. I am trying to not have a piece be placed when you click again.

```
var imageSwaped = false;

function clickOnBlankSpace(object)
{
    this.src="Directory/BlackPiece.png";
    imageSwaped = true;
    this.removeEventListener("click", clickOnBlankSpace);
    return;
}



var BlackPieces = document.getElementsByClassName("BlackPiece");
var RedPieces = document.getElementsByClassName("RedPiece");
var BlankSpaces = document.getElementsByClassName("BlankSpace");


for(var j = 0; j<BlackPieces.length;j++)
{
    var BlackPiece = BlackPieces[j];
    BlackPiece.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        this.src="Directory/BlackPieceH.png";
        this.className ="BlackPieceH";

        for(var j = 0; j<BlankSpaces.length;j++)
    {
            var BlankSpace = BlankSpaces[j];
            if (!imageSwaped) BlankSpace.addEventListener("click",     clickOnBlankSpace);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I wouldn’t define eventlisteners in loops but instead use event delegation and only bind one event listener doing one job with `e` as the function argument to the entire board (or field or `div`) and checking which piece has been clicked via `e.target`.

Comment: could you explain a little more about that Xufox? That sounds like a good alternative. The other problem I am having is being able to write conditionals with event listeners so that only when something is clicked on and if some other thing as occurred can the click work.